# Basic question about conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Consider $X$ and $Y$ tow random variables $\mathcal F_2$-measurable where $\mathcal F_1$ and $\mathcal F_2$ are two $\sigma$-algebras such that  $\mathcal F_1 \subseteq \mathcal F_2 $.

Can we always say that $\mathbb E [X ~Y| \mathcal F_1] = \mathbb E[X~\mathbb E [Y | \mathcal F_2]  | \mathcal F_1]$  ? Shouldn't $X$ and $Y$ be independent ?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need $X$ is $\mathcal{F}_2$-measurable, which gives:
$$
E[XY|\mathcal{F_2}]=X E[Y|\mathcal{F}_2].
$$
Now, using $\mathcal{F}_1\subset\mathcal{F}_2$ and iterated conditioning for the first equality below, we have
$$
E[XY|\mathcal{F}_1]=E[E[XY|\mathcal{F_2}]|\mathcal{F}_1]=E[XE[Y|\mathcal{F_2}]|\mathcal{F}_1].
$$

Comment: Yes of course! Thx